# How to configure EventStore to work with SQL Azure as storage?

Tags: azure-sql-database, cqrs, neventstore

I'm looking for an example of how to configure Jonathan Oliver's EventStore to work with SQL Azure. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a connection string which points to SQL Azure (instead of a local SQL Server instance) and then then use the SqlStorageEngine.  Everything will work as normal.